# How to make text to speech on Raspberry Pi Pico W

Tags: out-of-memory, artificial-intelligence, text-to-speech, raspberry-pi-pico

I am trying to to make a simple voice assistant using python. However, after months of hard work, I realized that the TTS I was using (pyttsx3) will not load onto the Raspberry Pi Pico W. Is there any way to get TTS on the Pico?

I have tried using the Hugging face inference API for my code, so I used this snippet:

```
import network
import socket
import machine
import urequests as requests
ssid = 'My Wi-Fi network '
password = 'My Wi-Fi password'
wlan = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
wlan.active(True)
wlan.connect(ssid, password)
print("internet connected sucessfully")

API_URL = "https://api-inference.huggingface.co/models/facebook/fastspeech2-en-ljspeech"
headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}

def query(payload):
        response = requests.post(API_URL, headers=headers, json=payload)
        return response.json()
        
output = query({
        "inputs": "The answer to the universe is 42",
})
```

(Note that in my real code I put my actual API token and Wi-Fi password)

However, every time I run the code (with actual API token) it gives me the same error:

```
internet connected sucessfully
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 20, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 17, in query
  File "urequests.py", line 33, in json
  File "urequests.py", line 20, in content
MemoryError: memory allocation failed, allocating 119296 bytes
```

what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the data volume it overpass the SRAM memory.

Please check out the Raspberry Pi Pico components and checkout what is a microcontroller. You always need put a program into a flash memory and create a comunication protocol, if you want use the Raspberry Pi Pico remotely.

https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/pico/pico-product-brief.pdf

https://raspberrypi.github.io/pico-sdk-doxygen/modules.html